# C2DM- detecting how application is launched

Tags: android, android-c2dm

so we have an iOS app and an Android app that each utilize their respective notification method frameworks... iOS has push and Android has C2DM (until we bring it up to GCM)... all is well on iOS, but i'm looking for a method of detecting if the app was launched by clicking a C2DM message (similar to the functionality of didFinishLaunchingWithOptions on iOS).

Currently, when the push message is received on Android, i do whatever processing that i need to do based on the data contained within the message's payload... so when the user launches the app their experience is determined by what was in that push message. This is the case regardless of whether they launch by pressing the icon on the home screen/history or push message. Ideally we'd like this to happen only if they select that message, and if they select the app from the home/history screen then it should launch normally.

Answer (score 0):

You can save some data in the SharedPreferences on your onMessage listener in the GCMIntentService intent class. The GCM listener belongs to your package app after all.
What you save depends on your app and your message payload, but it may be whatever you want.
Then on your onCreate function of the Activity launched when clicking on the notification, you read the Shared Preferences to see whether you come from the GCM notification or not. Remember to clear the variable you save in the SharedPreferences so that next time that the user opens the app, it displays the content properly.

You have an example here. Unfortunately I cannot try it right now but it's useful to see the idea. It's quite similar to G2DM so you have to look for the equivalent in your case.

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    /*... other functions of the class */

    /**
     * Method called on Receiving a new message
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
        String message = intent.getExtras().getString("your_message");

        // notifies user
        generateNotification(context, message);
    }

    /**
     * Issues a notification to inform the user that server has sent a message.
     */
    private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

        // Save your data in the shared preferences
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("YourPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);  
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = prefs.edit();  
        prefEditor.putBoolean("comesFromGCMNotification", true);  
        prefEditor.commit(); 

        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        // Play default notification sound
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);     

    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for the response. :-) this is very simliar to what i'm already doing, although obviously without using sharedprefs for what we're talking about. what i'm having trouble wrapping my head around is the "comesFromGCMNotification" part and how exactly i could tell if the user launched from the notification or not. It seems to me that after the user gets a notification and "comesFromGCMNotification" gets set, if they launch the app without selecting the notification then "comesFromGCMNotification" is still true and whatever processing will still be done. am i wrong in my reasoning here?

Comment: @MrTristan Check that you are using the same preferences in both places (Activity and GCMIntentService). In my example they are called "YourPrefs". You can also check the default return value when you ask for a preference which doesn't exist. To test this, use a String instead of a boolean for "comesFromGCMNotification" and check that the result is really something you put instead of the default value (probably an empty string or maybe null).

Comment: i think i worded my comment incorrectly. reading the value of comesFromGCMNotification isn't the issue... it's that i think that at a conceptional level that the flow will be wrong. I think that after you receive a notification and you set that preference upon receiving it, it will still be true when you launch the app without choosing the notification... I want to be able to have a different experience based on whether you launch the app by selecting the notification or launch the app by way of the home screen.